# Qual a causa de usar SELECT null FROM RDB$DATABASE

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

Não estou entendendo este `SELECT null FROM RDB$DATABASE`:

```sql
SELECT CK.IDCHEK,
       CK.DESCHE,
       (SELECT null FROM RDB$DATABASE) AS ENTEGU
FROM TC_CHECKL CK
ORDER BY CK.IDCHEK
```

Parece que vai em uma tabela interna do banco e não traz nada. Mais à frente no código o programador está salvando isso com *insert* direto no banco no evento *onDraw*.

Answer (score 1):

A princípio, nenhuma. Em se tratando de SQL, levando em conta as versões 2.0 em diante do Firebird, o código que você mostrou não é melhor que o código abaixo:

```
SELECT CK.IDCHEK,
       CK.DESCHE,
       null AS ENTEGU
FROM TC_CHECKL CK
ORDER BY CK.IDCHEK
```

Fiz uma busca por possíveis bugs no Firebird, mas não encontrei nenhum relacionado à query.
Então, além de possível erro do programador que fez o SQL, acredito que duas coisas poderiam ser as causas:

1) Devido à compatibilidade com os componentes usados no Delphi. Talvez usando o SQL da minha resposta, os componentes detectem o campo ENTEGU como se fosse de um tipo diferente (float ou string) ao do SQL atual.

2) O Select era mais complicado, usando outros campos, mas foi otimizado. Para evitar possíveis erros, o programador manteve o `(SELECT null FROM RDB$DATABASE)`.

Comment: EMBarbosa está correto, não há motivo para o uso. Se tentarmos pensar em motivos para isso, o cara que fez essa sql talvez usasse essa seleção como um ponto de substituição. Exemplo: Em tempo de execução, por meio de um StringReplace, ele talvez trocasse o 'null' por um determinado campo e o rdb$database por uma tabela. Isso nesse contexto criaria a possibilidade de definir em tempo de execução de onde o valor do campo viria. O próprio uso desse processo dentro de um 'onDraw' revela um certo grau de inexperiência do cara, pois esse evento não é apropriado para  abrir queryes nem de longe

Comment: Estou sendo negativado sem explicação aqui. Mas eu acredito piamente que a resposta está correta. Se  desejarem podem me mostrar onde estou errado.

Answer (score -1):

Isso é uma forma de executar consultas que retornem apenas um registro. Creio que o Firebird não tenha suporte a TOP 1. Seguem exemplos nesse sentido: http://www.tecnobyte.com.br/dica9.html?pagina=dica9.html

Caso a versão atual permita consultas que retornem apenas um registro sem usar a forma acima, pode valer a pena refatorar em nome da clareza.

Comment: Seria para dar um TOP 1 na subquery? Por que não usar `NULL AS ENTEGU` diretamente?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, isso faz com que a consulta retorne apenas um resultado (o primeiro de acordo com o `ORDER`). Se incluísse NULL, retornaria todos os registros com o valor da terceira coluna como NULL

Comment: TOP não tem nada a ver com o caso. O Firebird aceita tanto a cláusula [FIRST x SKIP y](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-first-skip), como [ROWS](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-select-rows) que tem justamente o objetivo de limitar o número de registros mostrados.